# Entity Framework Association Performance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following association.. GroupFile has a one to many relationship with MappedFolders (via the MappedFolder navigation property).

[image]

I would expect the next line to do an update:

```
groupFile.MappedFolder = _mappedFoldersRepository.Query(m => m.FolderName == "Unassigned").FirstOrDefault();
```

The Query (according to the profiler) is executing this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP ( 1 ) [Extent1].[MappedFolderId] AS [MappedFolderId],
                 [Extent1].[FolderPath]     AS [FolderPath],
                 [Extent1].[FolderName]     AS [FolderName],
                 [Extent1].[HotFolder]      AS [HotFolder],
                 [Extent1].[Workstation]    AS [Workstation]
FROM   [dbo].[MappedFolders] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  N'Unassigned' = [Extent1].[FolderName]
```

But according to Entity Framework Profiler, the assignment itself is executing this SQL statement prior to beginning the transaction:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Id]                          AS [Id],
       [Extent1].[Path]                        AS [Path],
       [Extent1].[Status]                      AS [Status],
       [Extent1].[DateAdded]                   AS [DateAdded],
       [Extent1].[DateLastUpdated]             AS [DateLastUpdated],
       [Extent1].[JobSetup_SetupId]            AS [JobSetup_SetupId],
       [Extent1].[Group_GroupId]               AS [Group_GroupId],
       [Extent1].[MappedFolder_MappedFolderId] AS [MappedFolder_MappedFolderId]
FROM   [dbo].[GroupFiles] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[MappedFolder_MappedFolderId] = 7 /* @EntityKeyValue1 */
```

I must be missing something subtle (or not so subtle) but I'm not sure why that SQL statement is needed....
UPDATE:
Looking further into what the profiler is telling me, the SQL Statement is associated with the following:

```
public virtual MappedFolders MappedFolder
{
    get { return _mappedFolder; }
    set
    {
        if (!ReferenceEquals(_mappedFolder, value))
        {
            var previousValue = _mappedFolder;
            _mappedFolder = value;
            FixupMappedFolder(previousValue);
        }
    }
}


private void FixupMappedFolder(MappedFolders previousValue)
{
    if (previousValue != null && previousValue.GroupFiles.Contains(this))
    {
        previousValue.GroupFiles.Remove(this);
    }

    if (MappedFolder != null)
    {   
        // THIS IS WHAT THE SQL STATEMENT IS FOR!!!!!
        if (!MappedFolder.GroupFiles.Contains(this))
        {
            MappedFolder.GroupFiles.Add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The generated code is checking the GroupFiles collection of the mapped folder to see if it has already been added?

Comment: If I make it so that the association is navigational ONLY from GroupFile -> MappedFolder (i.e., remove the navigation property on MappedFolders), then it doesn't need to do that....

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the select statement used to retrieve the entity associated with this:

```
_mappedFoldersRepository.Query(m => m.FolderName == "Unassigned").FirstOrDefault();
```

The assignment to `groupFile.MappedFolder` doesn't update the database until you call `ObjectContext.SaveChanges`.  At that point you should see the update statement.

Comment: Updated my question above. The SQL Generated is selecting GroupFiles not the MappedFolders.. Its as if its checking to see if it exists in the children before adding it...